# Session invalidation for 2 different browsers

Tags: session, authentication, browser, wso2

I have an apps with the authentication using WSO2.
Let say now I have the scenario below:
1. Login to the same apps with same credential in 2 different browser (Chrome and FireFox)
2. I change my password of my apps in Chrome
3. I go back to FireFox and the apps session is still valid without logging out

My question is, how can I invalidate/logout all the session in all the browser if I change password?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your authentication protocol?

Comment: @Gayan Hi, it is using SAML.